# Give tight asymptotic bounds for the following recurrence. T(n) = 3T(n/3)+log n

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Give tight asymptotic bounds for the following recurrence. Justify your answers by
working out the details or by appealing to a case of the master theorem

$$T(n) = 3T\left(\frac n3\right)+\log(n)$$

I choose master's theorem to solve this recurrence

$a=3$, $b=3$ , $f(n)=\log(n)$  ---> stuck here

how can handle this recurrence to solve it by master theorem or is there other way to solve it without master theorem

Answer (score 1):

You have that (among other things) $\log(n) \in O \left (n^{0.5} \right )$. Since $0.5<\log_b(a)=\log_3(3)=1$, the first case of the master theorem tells you that $T(n) \in \Theta(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

We use the iteration method to find an explicit form. Given the recurrence:

$$ T(n) = 3T\left( \frac{n}{3} \right) + \log_3 n $$

we expand, getting:

$$ T(n) = \log_3 n + 3 \log_3 \frac{n}{3} + 3^2 \log_3 \frac{n}{3^2} + 3^3 \log_3 \frac{n}{3^3} + ... + 3^{\log_3 n} \log_3 1 $$

From which we conclude:

$$ T(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\log_3 n} 3^k \log \frac{n}{3^k} $$

We can reformulate, getting:

$$ T(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\log_3 n} 3^k \log_3 n - \sum_{k = 0}^{\log_3 n} k \cdot 3^k $$

Computing the sums of the series gives:

$$ T(n) = \log_3 n \left( \frac{3n - 1}{2} \right) - \frac{3}{4} \left( 1 - (1 + \log_3 n)n + 3n \log_3 n \right) $$
$$  = \frac{3n}{2} \log_3 n - \frac{1}{2} \log_3 n - \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{4} \left( n + n \log_3 n \right) - \frac{9}{4} n \log_3 n $$
$$  = \frac{3}{4}n - \frac{1}{2} \log_3 n - \frac{3}{4} $$

And so we have found an explicit form for the recurrence. We verify its validity using induction:

$$ T(n) = 3T\left( \frac{n}{3} \right) + \log_3 n $$
$$ = 3\left( \frac{3}{4} \frac{n}{3} - \frac{1}{2} \log_3 \frac{n}{3} - \frac{3}{4} \right) + \log_3 n $$
$$ = \frac{3}{4} n - \frac{3}{2} \log_3 \frac{n}{3} - \frac{9}{4} + \log_3 n $$
$$ = \frac{3}{4} n - \frac{3}{2} \left( \log_3 n - 1 \right) - \frac{9}{4} + \log_3 n $$
$$ = \frac{3}{4}n - \frac{1}{2} \log_3 n - \frac{3}{4} $$

And so we have verified the bound. This means $T(n) = \Theta(n)$.